# Cant run myApp.ipa after installing it from Diawi

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa, diawi

[image]I created an app using react native, I have tested it on my IOS devices by connecting them with xcode, but now i want to share myApp with others to test it. To do that I generated myApp.ipa file by archiving, simply I just navigate to Product -> Application -> myapp, after archive is done, i copied the file to a folder named Payload after compressing the file, changed the Payload.zip to myApp.ipa after that I upload it to the Diawi website then got the link, installed the app on my ios device but unfortunately i cant run it? myApp is shaded with black, and nothing is there in Setting -> General -> Profiles. what did i do wrong? or if there is a simple way to let other test myApp.ipa please share.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Didi you solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app is blacked out because the iOS device won't run any unsigned apps. Your app cannot be signed without a provisioning profile.

You cannot install an app on an iOS device without a provisioning profile. The only way to get a provisioning profile is to have either a paid developer account or an enterprise account.

To install an app on an iOS device without submitting to the app store requires use of either an `ad-hoc` or `enterprise` provisioning profile

#### ad-hoc

The only way to get an `ad-hoc` provisioning profile is to have a paid developer account. $99 per year. https://developer.apple.com/programs/

`ad-hoc` profiles have limits to the number of different devices that they can be installed on.

#### enterprise

The only way yo get an `enterprise` provisioning profile is to have an enterprise account. $299 per year https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

`enterprise` profiles don't have the same restrictions on the number of devices as `ad-hoc` profiles but you cannot submit to the app-store with an enterprise account.